# In python, how to company the number of overlapping subarray of two np arrays

Tags: python

I have two np.array A and B which store some picture samples, A.shape is (20000, 45, 45, 3) and B.shape is (100000, 45, 45, 3). I want to know how many pictures are the same with B.

I write this:

```
for i in list(A):
    if i in list(B):
        count = count + 1
```

But python told me that: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use `a.any()` or `a.all()`

How can I get the intersection of subarray between two 4-D nparrays?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
for img in A:
    if (img == B).all(axis=(1, 2, 3)).any():
        count += 1
```

Iterating through every image in `A`, we check if there is any image in `B` that is the same by using the `==` operator, which compares element-wise, and checks if there is a 3D array (i.e. all elements in axes 1, 2 & 3) that is the same as `img`. Then we use `any()`, since we only need one image in `B` to be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much!